# Uploading video to Firebase uing ngCordova ($cordovaCapture) in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, ngcordova

How to upload video that I record using my mobile.  I manage to upload the video  path to Firebase but when I want to use it in my view (html file), it does not work. Here is my code:

```
.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $cordovaCamera, $location, $cordovaCapture){
  var fb = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/videos");
  $scope.videos;
  $scope.record = function(){
      fb = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/videos");
      $scope.videos = $firebaseArray(fb);
      var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };
      $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
          function(videoData) {
              var i, path, len;
              var pathtogo;
              var pathtogostring;
              for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                  path = videoData[i].fullPath;
                  pathtogo = path.toString();
                  pathtogostring = pathtogo.substr(6);  
                  alert("Path of the video is = " + path.toString());                                      

                  obj = {
                      videoP: path,
                      videosrc: pathtogostring
                  }
                  $scope.videos.$add(obj);
                }
          },
          function(err) {
          }
      );
  }//end record
 })//end controller
```

My html file

```
  <div ng-repeat="video in videos" class="card">

    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        {{video.videoP}}
    </div>

    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        {{video.videosrc}}
    </div>

    <video controls>
        <source src="video.videosrc" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without running the app myself, but I do see an issue with your `record` function.

Don't initialize the `$firebaseArray` inside of the `record` function, do it when the controller initializes:

```
.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $cordovaCamera, $location, $cordovaCapture){
  var fb = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/videos");
  $scope.videos = $firebaseArray(fb);
  $scope.record = function record() {
     // ... your record code here 
  };
})
```

The `$firebaseArray` is in sync with the server, so it only needs to be created once.

*As for your display issue...*

You need to change the `src` attribute in `<source>` to `ng-src`, and use curlys `{{ }}` to interpolate:

```
<video controls>
    <source ng-src="{{video.videosrc}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[For more information on HTML attrs vs directives, see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055377/why-do-certain-html-elements-need-angular-js-directives-and-others-dont/22055426#22055426)

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location, $cordovaCapture){
var fb = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/videos");
$scope.videos;
$scope.record = function(){
    fb = new Firebase("https://myURL.firebaseio.com/videos");
  $scope.videos = $firebaseArray(fb);
  var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };
  $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
      function(videoData) {
          var i, path, len;
          var pathtogo;
          var pathtogostring;
          for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
              path = videoData[i].fullPath;
              pathtogo = path.toString();


              obj = {
                    videosrc: pathtogo 
              }
              $scope.videos.$add(obj);
            }
      },
      function(err) {
      }
  );
}//end record
 })//end controlle
```